# Unwrapping UILabel always returns nil

Tags: swift, uilabel, option-type

I've hooked a UILabel to my VC using the storyboard, does generating a weak var but connected to a storyboard reference. Anyway, whenever I try to unwrap it, all I get is a nil value. What confuses me the most is that I'm able to access it on another method. I've already safe unwrapped it, it avoids the compiler errors, but doesn't solve my problem.

The compiler message is: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is some of the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var linesLeftCountLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {

      super.viewDidLoad()

      skView = SKView(frame: sceneView.frame)
      skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

      //Create and configure the scene.
      scene = LogoRefactoryScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
      scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
      skView.presentScene(scene)

      tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "eraseLine:")
      tapGesture.delegate = self
      view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

      view.addSubview(skView)
    }
```

Here I'm able to access it:

```
  @IBAction func colorPickerOfColor(sender: UIButton) {

    var pickerName = ""

    switch sender.tag {

    case 0:
      pickerName = "green"

    case 1:
      pickerName = "red"

    case 2:
      pickerName = "blue"

    default:
      pickerName = "orange"
    }

    pickerName += "ColorPicker"
    colorPickerView.image = UIImage(named: pickerName)

    currentColorName = ColorSelection.fromRaw(sender.tag + 1)!.colorName

    let color = ColorSelection.fromRaw(sender.tag + 1)!.getSKColor()
    scene.lineColor = color
    linesLeftCountLabel.textColor = color
  }
```

Here is where the compiler complains:

```
  func lineHasBeenDrawn() {

    linesLeftCountLabel.text = "Any String"
  }
```

Comment: That makes no sense.. There's probably a bug where you are trying to change the code, we need to see some code to help you

Comment: @Heliem now I've posted the whole class :D Hope it helps

Comment: where is `lineHasBeenDrawn()` being called?

Comment: @Heliem it is a delegate method.

Comment: @Heliem but it's being called only after everything is already setup. So the label is already instantiated.

Comment: You need to provide more info such as full stacktrace. I can't work out which line in your sample code throws the exception

Comment: Are you sure that sender.tag **is not nil** and also that **its value plus 1 is in the 0...2 range**? Maybe you wanted to write `- 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that guys. lineHasDrawn is a delegate method, that's why the strange behaviour.
My bad.

Comment: why does it matter if it is a delegate method? I am having this exact same problem, did you ever find a work around solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have connected the referencing outlet in the storyboard to the IBOutlet of your code

[image]